# Trying to add commas in an array printer

Tags: java, arrays

I think my problem is within the if and else statements. The program needs to print the array with commas in between and brackets around it. Does something needed to be added to else? I'm fairly new to so im sure the solution is simple. Thanks

```
public class array {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] oneD = {5 ,6 ,7 ,8};

int[][] twoD ={{2,4,6,8},{8,7,9,1},{3,5,1,2}};

int[][] twoD2 = {{1,2},{3,4,5},{6},{7,8,9}};

printArray(oneD);
printArray(twoD);
printArray(twoD2);



}

public static void printArray(int[] arr) {

System.out.print("[");  

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)

{

if (i < arr.length-1)
System.out.print(arr[i]);

else 
System.out.print(arr[i] + ",");

} 

System.out.print("]");
}




public static void printArray(int[] [] arr) {

System.out.print("[");

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)

printArray(arr[i]);

System.out.print("]");

}

}
```

Comment: You're going to need a second loop in case the array be two dimensional.  But, rather than reinventing the wheel, you should look into just using `Arrays.toString()` or `Arrays.deepToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap your condition:

```
if (i < arr.length - 1)    
    System.out.print(arr[i] + ",");    
else
    System.out.print(arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in your `if` condition,

```
if (i != arr.length-1)
    System.out.print(arr[i] + ",");
else 
    System.out.print(arr[i]);
```

if index is not at the last element print 'a[i],'
else print 'a[i]'.

Makes more sense right?

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void printArray(int[] arr) {

   System.out.print("[");

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)

    {  System.out.print(arr[i]);

        if (i < arr.length-1)
            System.out.print( ",");

    }

    System.out.print("],");

}
```